# Different formatting for a particular item in beamer TOC

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

Is it possible in beamer TOC to show a particular item (subsection) as grayed out?

Comment: Can you provide the community with some code that provides the foundation from which they can provide you with a solution? Something that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and it should show a ToC. Then you can be a bit more specific and say "I want item 3 to be grayed out *always*" (or something similar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the colour for sections in toc before and after the subsections you want to modify:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame} 

\section{bla}

\subsection{blub}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setbeamercolor{subsection in toc}{fg=red}}
\subsection{blub}\frame{}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setbeamercolor{subsection in toc}{fg=black}}

\subsection{blubbb}\frame{}

\end{document}
```

[image]